# Create input fields dynamically with values and column names from database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I create inputs using the information in the columns for example if a field is called `about_content` it outputs a label of About Content with an input field. This works fine for inserting however I want to use this code similarly to `UPDATE` and I want to display to users the current value of a field as entered in the database. For example if `about_content = Hello World!` I want the input value to reflect that. Is there a way of doing this dynamically?

```
<?php

require('dbc.php');

mysql_select_db($db);
$resultInput = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM about WHERE Field NOT IN 
('id', 'created', 'date_modified', 'last_modified', 'update', 'type', 'bodytext') 
AND Field NOT REGEXP '_image'"); // selects only the columns I want

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM about WHERE id=".$_GET['id']); // values I want to put into the values for <input>

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result) && $column = mysql_num_rows ($resultInput)) {

    foreach($row as $column => $value){
        echo '<label>'.$column.'<input name="'.$column.'" type="input" value="'.$value.'"></label><br>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Does `SHOW COLUMNS` works in sql query?

Comment: Yes currently every part works perfectly separately but the problem is idk how to combine the input w the values

Comment: where are you storing the values currently?

Comment: the values are stored in the database, currently localhost

Comment: so write a query to get the values from the database and like you are able to print labels you can print the values in the input box.

Comment: Do you want to restricted columns from about table?

Comment: Yea bc certain fields I do not want the user to be able to edit. Such as modified which is created by a timestamp

Answer (score 1):

See the spot you've marked with an arrow? Instead of the string `(1)`, set `value` to the appropriate database value you read in `$result` (not in `$resultInput`).

Here's how: use `mysql_fetch_assoc` for your `SELECT` query, not `mysql_fetch_row`. There will be only one row, so fetch it *before* you start generating the form. You'll then have a named array with the row values, and you can grab each field by name and put it in the form.

If you don't understand how to do that, check the php documentation for `mysql_fetch_assoc`.

And escape your `$_GET['id']` like you were told in your last question. You're begging to be pwned!

Comment: Thanks I'll worry about security after I get the main function to work... and the (1) was just so ppl could understand maybe what i wanted to do.. I'm still confused how to set the db value to $result, only when i have a while function with $resultInput to get the column names

Answer (score 1):

See [mysql_fetch_field](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-field.php).

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
//loop creates inputs
//make $resultInput object to array.
$i=0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $meta = mysql_fetch_field($result, $i);
    if(in_array($meta->name, $resultInput )){
    echo '<div class="wrapper"><label>' . ucfirst(str_replace('_', ' ',$meta->name)) . 
    '<br><input name="' . $meta->name . 
    '" type="text" class="input" value="$row[$meta->name]"><br></label></div>';
    }
    $i++;
 }
}
```

Comment: Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, resource given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 17

Comment: I have said to make $resultInput object to array i.e. $resultInput=$resultInput->result()

Comment: Its parsing nothing... It has something to do with the $i when I change the value to for example 2 I get my second field. Also heres my array $resultInput = array("page_header", "sub_header", "content_short", "content");

Comment: @Alex: I havn't tested it. You might have understood logic now. I have updated answer. Check it.

Comment: still isnt outputting anything. The logic makes sense, but i cant find the error.

Comment: Do you get any error? Where you gets stucked? Can you come to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13215/indian-enthusiast-programmers?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include('db.php');
if (isset($_POST['btn'])) {

    $dcolumn = $_POST['dyncolumns'];
    $dvalue = $_POST['dynfields'];

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $query = "INSERT into addtable(name,mobile,address)VALUES('" . $name . "','" . $mobile . "','" . $address . "')";
    $result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
    $id = mysql_insert_id();


    if ($dcolumn) {
        foreach ($dcolumn as $key => $value) {
            $result1 = "show COLUMNS from addtable like '.$value.'";
            $exists = mysql_query($result1)or die(mysql_error());
            $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($exists);

            if ($data==TRUE) {
                $query = "update addtable set $value = '" . $dvalue[$key] . "' where id=$id";
            } else {
                $query1 = "ALTER TABLE addtable ADD $value varchar(45)";
                $result2 = mysql_query($query1)or die(mysql_error());
                $query = "update addtable set $value = '" . $dvalue[$key] . "' where id=$id";
                $result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
            }
        }
    }


}
?>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var table = document.getElementById("insert");
        var row = table.insertRow(3);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell1.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='dyncolumns[]'>";
        cell2.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='dynfields[]' >";
    }
</script>
<html>
    <body>
        <form name="insert" method="post">

            <table border="2" align="center" id="insert">
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td><td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Mobile</td><td><input type="text" name="mobile" maxlength="10"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Address</td><td><input type="text" name="address" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="btn" value="submit"></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
            <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" name="add" value="Add">
            <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you add some comments or an explanation to your code?