# fetch field not working

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, object

There seems to be a problem with this script. Whenever I change the value of $i to like 2 or something it outputs A field not ALL fields. I am not sure what is wrong.

Additionally is it possible to do something like this? Basically there are more fields in the result query, but I only want to output the values of the fields listed in the result query that I want the user to be able to edit (displayed in resultInput)

```
<?php
require('dbc.php');
mysql_select_db($db);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM about WHERE id=1");
$resultInput = array('page_header', 'sub_header', 'content', 'content_short');


if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
//loop creates inputs
//make $resultInput object to array.
$i=0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $meta = mysql_fetch_field($result, $i);
    if(in_array($meta->name, $resultInput )){
    echo '<div class="wrapper"><label>' . ucfirst(str_replace('_', ' ',$meta->name)) . 
    '<br><input name="' . $meta->name . 
    '" type="text" class="input" value="'.$row[$meta->name].'"><br></label></div>';
    }
    $i++;
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: Your output is likely to return 1 field for each row, and go across so first like shows field0, second row shows field 1, third field 2... see if you can now spot your error

Comment: oh i see. but how does one fix this? i want all fields and values for those fields to show up

Comment: Then you havent thought how things work through..

Comment: me and a friend have unfortunately we just dont see it

Comment: Given my explaination of what you code does, that should have lead you to your answer - I have posted code below.

Comment: @all: For more info, this is relating from. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283191/create-input-fields-dynamically-with-values-and-column-names-from-database and http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/4353053#4353053

Comment: Is this by any chance your homework?

Comment: nope im actually a business student. more of a side project. trying to get back into php as it has been a couple of years. and im interested in it generally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this isnt how I would do it.. ive taken your code  and made it so it should work..

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
//loop creates inputs 
//make $resultInput object to array. 

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    { 
        $i=0; 
        while ( $i<   mysql_num_fields($result)) 
        {
            $meta = mysql_fetch_field($result, $i); 
            if(in_array($meta->name, $resultInput ))
            { 
              echo '<div class="wrapper"><label>' . ucfirst(str_replace('_', ' ',$meta->name)) .  
             '<br><input name="' . $meta->name .  
             '" type="text" class="input" value="'.$row[$meta->name].'"><br></label></div>'; 
            } 
            $i++; 
        } 
    } 
    ?>
```

FYI

Heres how I would have done it, although looking at it, Im not happy with the echo.. but..

```
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    { 
        foreach ($row as $fieldname => $value)
        {
            if (in_array($fieldname, $resultInput )) Display_data($fieldname,$value);
        } 
    } 

function Display_data($fieldname,$value)
{
              echo '<div class="wrapper"><label>' . ucfirst(str_replace('_', ' ',$fieldname)) .  
             '<br><input name="' . $fieldname .  
             '" type="text" class="input" value="'.$value.'"><br></label></div>'; 
}
```

Comment: I know, but if I do this perhaps he will see where the logic went wrong.. rather than what I'd do.. My point was not about perfect code - so Im a bit annoyed at the down vote, when Im trying to show the logic error not the coding uglyness.

Comment: yea i see it now (wasnt me who downvoted). and it makes sense. whats so bad about the code though? granted there are a few while loops

Comment: I appreciate your trying to teach a newbie, but since this answer will stand as general reference, people will copy and paste it because it works. So I'd rather you write an *here's your error and here's the correct way* answer...

Comment: Problem is you can often do your own way and the person wont see whats wrong with theirs. I'll do a "heres a better way" ..

Comment: regards to the new code: thats actually what i had before but didnt go as far as to add the inarray whitin the foreeach (really stupid of me)... for sure way better code haha while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result) ) {

    foreach($row as $column => $value){
        echo "Row: $column - $value<br />";
    }
}